# How come random matrices can predict energy spectra of heavy atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, mathematical-physics, string-theory, nuclear-physics

Some of the applications of random matrices is to find the spectra of heavy atoms in nuclear physics which are usually difficult to find otherwise.

How can starting from randomness of some kind, such as random matrices, lead to prediction of that sort?

Any idea why this work?

Random matrices are used in string theory too, may be some string theorist here can shed some light on this topic

Revo

Comment: If you answer this question, you'll be famous. The reason that the normal distribution works so well for many applications is the central limit theorem ... a lot of small effects tend to add up to a normal distribution. Possibly, something similar is going on here.

Comment: I'm curious about what sort of algorithm uses random matrices to calculate spectral lines...

Comment: @Colin, it's not so much an algorithm, just an observation that the *distribution* of energy eigenvalues for many heavy nuclei happen to fall upon the distribution of eigenvalues of a certain class of random matrices (gaussian um... something (orthogonal, unitary, symplectic - I forget which) ensemble). While perhaps not physically satisfying, I think Peter's comment is the best answer to this question.

Comment: @wsc: It's not just heavy nuclei and random matrices; there are a number of other random processes which give rise to this same probability distribution of eigenvalues, and as far as I know, nobody has yet found a satisfactory explanation for why this happens.

Comment: @Revo: String theorists would be the *last* people to know why this happens; no knock on stringy guys, but deriving the properties of even light nuclei from just quarks and gluons is already an immensely heady task. (not to mention that calculating the spectra of heavy nuclei from nucleons and pions is also a difficult task, thus the immense beauty of their distribution being reproduced by the GUE.)

Comment: @Peter Shor: speaking as a statistical physicist, I thought that this was *exactly* what people thought? (It's certainly how I think  of it...) The argument is essentially a universality class/renormalisation group one.

Comment: Colins curiosity is very much justified. One should know what "atomic spectra" are about, before mixing up nuclear spectra with them!

Comment: @PeterShor:  Genneth is right about this, I think.  The correct mathematical argument will boil down to stating, as the statistical physicists do, that the central limit theorem applies to most nuclear observables of this kind, because the long distance behavior of most effective QFT models is spherically symmetric and Gaussian.

Comment: @user1504: I believe the central limit theorem doesn't apply, at least not in any obvious way; the central limit theorem says things converge to normal distributions, and the eigenvalues of a random matrix do not follow a normal distribution. There has to be a different theorem which not only hasn't been proved, but which we currently don't even know enough about to state exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the classical system consisting of nucleons interacting with a realistic pair potential is chaotic. A classically chaotic system careens between unstable periodic orbits, which in a path-integralish view ( gutzwiller trace formula) tells you that nearby energy levels are concentrated on completely different periodic orbits, so that they have mixed with each other strongly if you consider the unperturbed wavefunctions to be homogenous ( Heller scarring) The statistics of random matrix eigenvalues is based on the principle of heavy generic mixing between energy levels, leading to level repulsion. By contrast, classically integrable systems have energy levels which are regularly spaced, coming as they do from semiclassically setting the action variables to be integers. Each action variable gives a smooth level spacing, and the spacings add up linearly, to produce a uniformish distribution of energy levels without level repulsion.

Comment: Could you please provide some references?

Comment: This is just folklore from the 90s. That an integrable system has no level repulsion is an ancient result, probably known to Bohr/Sommerfeld/Einstein. There's a nice review of the Gutzwiller trace formula here: http://www.teorfys.uu.se/files/Martin_Lubcke_gutz.pdf. Here is a review of scarring, focusing on the predicted corrections to random matrix theory:http://xxx.lanl.gov/pdf/chao-dyn/9810013v1. The basic answer I give is more elementary than the corrections, and is found in the early pages of this book: http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=oo03LoIDYQsC